# 2 jquery scripts aren't working together

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I've been working with these 2 Jquery files for a while, trying to debug them but I can't figure out why they don't work together.

Any advice would be awesome and greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

```
========START JS#1=====================
window.onerror=function(desc,page,line,chr){
/* alert('JavaScript error occurred! \n'
  +'\nError description: \t'+desc
  +'\nPage address:      \t'+page
  +'\nLine number:       \t'+line
 );*/
}

$(function(){
 $('a').focus(function(){this.blur();});
 SI.Files.stylizeAll();
 slider.init();
 mc.init();

 $('input.text-default').each(function(){
  $(this).attr('default',$(this).val());
 }).focus(function(){
  if($(this).val()==$(this).attr('default'))
   $(this).val('');
 }).blur(function(){
  if($(this).val()=='')
   $(this).val($(this).attr('default'));
 });

 $('input.text,textarea.text').focus(function(){
  $(this).addClass('textfocus');
 }).blur(function(){
  $(this).removeClass('textfocus');
 });

 var popopenobj=0,popopenaobj=null;
 $('a.popup').click(function(){
  var pid=$(this).attr('rel').split('|')[0],_os=parseInt($(this).attr('rel').split('|')[1]);
  var pobj=$('#'+pid);
  if(!pobj.length)
   return false;
  if(typeof popopenobj=='object' && popopenobj.attr('id')!=pid){
   popopenobj.hide(50);
   $(popopenaobj).parent().removeClass(popopenobj.attr('id').split('-')[1]+'-open');
   popopenobj=null;
  }
  return false;
 });
 $('p.images img').click(function(){
  var newbg=$(this).attr('src').split('bg/bg')[1].split('-thumb')[0];
  $(document.body).css('backgroundImage','url('+_siteRoot+'images/bg/bg'+newbg+'.jpg)');

  $(this).parent().find('img').removeClass('on');
  $(this).addClass('on');
  return false;
 });
 $(window).load(function(){
  $.each(css_ims,function(){(new Image()).src=_siteRoot+'css/images/'+this;});
  $.each(css_cims,function(){
   var css_im=this;
   $.each(['blue','purple','pink','red','grey','green','yellow','orange'],function(){
    (new Image()).src=_siteRoot+'css/'+this+'/'+css_im;
   });
  });
 }); 
 $('div.sc-large div.img:has(div.tml)').each(function(){
  $('div.tml',this).hide();
  $(this).append('<a href="#" class="tml_open">&nbsp;</a>').find('a').css({
   left:parseInt($(this).offset().left)+864,top:parseInt($(this).offset().top)+1
  }).click(function(){
   $(this).siblings('div.tml').slideToggle();
   return false;
  }).focus(function(){this.blur();}); 
 });
});
var slider={
 num:-1,
 cur:0,
 cr:[],
 al:null,
 at:10*1000,
 ar:true,
 init:function(){
  if(!slider.data || !slider.data.length)
   return false;

  var d=slider.data;
  slider.num=d.length;
  var pos=Math.floor(Math.random()*1);//slider.num);
  for(var i=0;i<slider.num;i++){
   $('#'+d[i].id).css({left:((i-pos)*1000)});
   $('#slide-nav').append('<a id="slide-link-'+i+'" href="#" onclick="slider.slide('+i+');return false;" onfocus="this.blur();">'+(i+1)+'</a>');
  }

  $('img,div#slide-controls',$('div#slide-holder')).fadeIn();
  slider.text(d[pos]);
  slider.on(pos);
  slider.cur=pos;
  window.setTimeout('slider.auto();',slider.at);
 },
 auto:function(){
  if(!slider.ar)
   return false;

  var next=slider.cur+1;
  if(next>=slider.num) next=0;
  slider.slide(next);
 },
 slide:function(pos){
  if(pos<0 || pos>=slider.num || pos==slider.cur)
   return;

  window.clearTimeout(slider.al);
  slider.al=window.setTimeout('slider.auto();',slider.at);

  var d=slider.data;
  for(var i=0;i<slider.num;i++)
   $('#'+d[i].id).stop().animate({left:((i-pos)*1000)},1000,'swing');

  slider.on(pos);
  slider.text(d[pos]);
  slider.cur=pos;
 },
 on:function(pos){
  $('#slide-nav a').removeClass('on');
  $('#slide-nav a#slide-link-'+pos).addClass('on');
 },
 text:function(di){
  slider.cr['a']=di.client;
  slider.cr['b']=di.desc;
  slider.ticker('#slide-client span',di.client,0,'a');
  slider.ticker('#slide-desc',di.desc,0,'b');
 },
 ticker:function(el,text,pos,unique){
  if(slider.cr[unique]!=text)
   return false;

  ctext=text.substring(0,pos)+(pos%2?'-':'_');
  $(el).html(ctext);

  if(pos==text.length)
   $(el).html(text);
  else
   window.setTimeout('slider.ticker("'+el+'","'+text+'",'+(pos+1)+',"'+unique+'");',30);
 }
};
// STYLING FILE INPUTS 1.0 | Shaun Inman <http://www.shauninman.com/> | 2007-09-07
if(!window.SI){var SI={};};
SI.Files={
 htmlClass:'SI-FILES-STYLIZED',
 fileClass:'file',
 wrapClass:'cabinet',

 fini:false,
 able:false,
 init:function(){
  this.fini=true;
 },
 stylize:function(elem){
  if(!this.fini){this.init();};
  if(!this.able){return;};

  elem.parentNode.file=elem;
  elem.parentNode.onmousemove=function(e){
   if(typeof e=='undefined') e=window.event;
   if(typeof e.pageY=='undefined' &&  typeof e.clientX=='number' && document.documentElement){
    e.pageX=e.clientX+document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
    e.pageY=e.clientY+document.documentElement.scrollTop;
   };
   var ox=oy=0;
   var elem=this;
   if(elem.offsetParent){
    ox=elem.offsetLeft;
    oy=elem.offsetTop;
    while(elem=elem.offsetParent){
     ox+=elem.offsetLeft;
     oy+=elem.offsetTop;
    };
   };
  };
 },
 stylizeAll:function(){
  if(!this.fini){this.init();};
  if(!this.able){return;};
 }
};


=========END JS FILE #1========================


=========START JS FILE #2======================


/*
 * Superfish v1.4.8 - jQuery menu widget
 * Copyright (c) 2008 Joel Birch
 *
 * Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses:
 *  http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 *  http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
 *
 * CHANGELOG: http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/changelog.txt
 */

;(function($){
    $.fn.superfish = function(op){

        var sf = $.fn.superfish,
            c = sf.c,
            $arrow = $(['<span class="',c.arrowClass,'"> &#187;</span>'].join('')),
            over = function(){
                var $$ = $(this), menu = getMenu($$);
                clearTimeout(menu.sfTimer);
                $$.showSuperfishUl().siblings().hideSuperfishUl();
            },
            out = function(){
                var $$ = $(this), menu = getMenu($$), o = sf.op;
                clearTimeout(menu.sfTimer);
                menu.sfTimer=setTimeout(function(){
                    o.retainPath=($.inArray($$[0],o.$path)>-1);
                    $$.hideSuperfishUl();
                    if (o.$path.length && $$.parents(['li.',o.hoverClass].join('')).length<1){over.call(o.$path);}
                },o.delay); 
            },
            getMenu = function($menu){
                var menu = $menu.parents(['ul.',c.menuClass,':first'].join(''))[0];
                sf.op = sf.o[menu.serial];
                return menu;
            },
            addArrow = function($a){ $a.addClass(c.anchorClass).append($arrow.clone()); };

        return this.each(function() {
            var s = this.serial = sf.o.length;
            var o = $.extend({},sf.defaults,op);
            o.$path = $('li.'+o.pathClass,this).slice(0,o.pathLevels).each(function(){
                $(this).addClass([o.hoverClass,c.bcClass].join(' '))
                    .filter('li:has(ul)').removeClass(o.pathClass);
            });
            sf.o[s] = sf.op = o;

            $('li:has(ul)',this)[($.fn.hoverIntent && !o.disableHI) ? 'hoverIntent' : 'hover'](over,out).each(function() {
                if (o.autoArrows) addArrow( $('>a:first-child',this) );
            })
            .not('.'+c.bcClass)
                .hideSuperfishUl();

            var $a = $('a',this);
            $a.each(function(i){
                var $li = $a.eq(i).parents('li');
                $a.eq(i).focus(function(){over.call($li);}).blur(function(){out.call($li);});
            });
            o.onInit.call(this);

        }).each(function() {
            var menuClasses = [c.menuClass];
            if (sf.op.dropShadows  && !($.browser.msie && $.browser.version < 7)) menuClasses.push(c.shadowClass);
            $(this).addClass(menuClasses.join(' '));
        });
    };

    var sf = $.fn.superfish;
    sf.o = [];
    sf.op = {};
    sf.IE7fix = function(){
        var o = sf.op;
        if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version > 6 && o.dropShadows && o.animation.opacity!=undefined)
            this.toggleClass(sf.c.shadowClass+'-off');
        };
    sf.c = {
        bcClass     : 'sf-breadcrumb',
        menuClass   : 'sf-js-enabled',
        anchorClass : 'sf-with-ul',
        arrowClass  : 'sf-sub-indicator',
        shadowClass : 'sf-shadow'
    };
    sf.defaults = {
        hoverClass  : 'sfHover',
        pathClass   : 'overideThisToUse',
        pathLevels  : 1,
        delay       : 2500,
        animation   : {opacity:'show'},
        speed       : 'fast',
        autoArrows  : false,
        dropShadows : false,
        disableHI   : false,        // true disables hoverIntent detection
        onInit      : function(){}, // callback functions
        onBeforeShow: function(){},
        onShow      : function(){},
        onHide      : function(){}
    };
    $.fn.extend({
        hideSuperfishUl : function(){
            var o = sf.op,
                not = (o.retainPath===true) ? o.$path : '';
            o.retainPath = false;
            var $ul = $(['li.',o.hoverClass].join(''),this).add(this).not(not).removeClass(o.hoverClass)
                    .find('>ul').hide().css('visibility','hidden');
            o.onHide.call($ul);
            return this;
        },
        showSuperfishUl : function(){
            var o = sf.op,
                sh = sf.c.shadowClass+'-off',
                $ul = this.addClass(o.hoverClass)
                    .find('>ul:hidden').css('visibility','visible');
            sf.IE7fix.call($ul);
            o.onBeforeShow.call($ul);
            $ul.animate(o.animation,o.speed,function(){ sf.IE7fix.call($ul); o.onShow.call($ul); });
            return this;
        }
    });

})(jQuery);


=============== end js file #2 ============================
```

Comment: @wilwaldon -- this isn't the place to have *all* your work done for you. ;-)  What errors are you seeing on a page with these two plugins added to it?

Comment: can somebody edit this and use markdown so the code ie easier to read?

Comment: ...  Can you please post a reduced version which still replicates the problem you are having?  Try removing code blocks at a time until things start working (then put it back remove other ones, etc.).

Comment: I totally understand where you're coming from with your comment :)I'm a total noob and my brain is pretty much going to explode. 

I've uploaded the files so you could take a look at them. The top menu doesn't work like it should, but the slideshow works fine.
I get these errors:
Message: Object expected
Line: 15
Char: 2
Code: 0
URI: http://wilwaldon.com/jquerybusted/assets/jqueryslidemenu.js
Message: 'mc' is undefined
Line: 14
Char: 2
Code: 0
URI: http://wilwaldon.com/jquerybusted/assets/scripts.js

http://wilwaldon.com/jquerybusted/ I appreciate your time and thank you for your help so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I noticed when I pulled open your site is that you have scripts getting called before you load your jQuery script (specifically `assets/jqueryslidemenu.js`). Try moving the jQuery to the first script being loaded.

Edit: After moving that file to the first position, it looks like this isn't the only issue though. There are 3 variables I can't find being declared anywhere. If this is expected, just ignore the update.
The variables `mc`, `css_ims`, and `css_cims` from scripts.js are the variables not defined.

Comment: You my friend, are a genius. I just learned a valuable lesson, thank you so much :)